# How can check logged user for signin in django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am new in django and i am trying to create signup and sign in for user. i have finished for sign up page and some user are doing sign up that's stored in my database. When i am going to sign in it can't find those user whose are already sign up. Would you please help me for this?

my view.py

```
def login_user(request):
    state = "Please log in below..."
    if request.POST:
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')        
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if  request.user.is_authenticated:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = 'email: '+str(email)+' and password: '+str(password)+' is not found'

    return render_to_response('signup_test.html',{'state':state, 'email': email},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Please read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in).

Answer (score 0):

The [`authenticate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend.authenticate) method checks a `username` and a `password`.

You should modify this line:

```
user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
```

to be:

```
user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
```

However, this is assuming that you have set up authentication to accept an email as a username.

Answer (score 0):

By default django support login with username so try some thing like

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        # Redirect to a success page.
    else:
        # Return a 'disabled account' error message
        ...
else:
```

Follow this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users

check your user in your database first

Comment: I have fallowed your instruction but still now its not working.

Comment: user save in your database ?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use the `set_password()` that inserts the encrypted password to create users. Example:

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save(commit = False)
    user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
    user.save()
```

[Login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in)

Answer (score 0):

> you just set the email field to unique, then it should allow unique
>   user only otherwise it will raise the validation error like "User with
>   this email already exists."